# Enter multiple criteria in a search engine ASP. MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, search-engine, criteria

I have the following code which looks into the "ProductCatalog" and returns items if found.
I need to edit the code in order for me to be able to enter multiple values or even special characters like >, <, and, or.

Is this possible?

```
    <div class="search">
@*@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "ProductCatalog", FormMethod.Get, new { name = "quickSearchform" }))*@
@using (Html.BeginForm("Search", "ProductCatalog", FormMethod.Get, new { name = "searchform", id = "searchform", onsubmit = "return validateSearch();" }))
{
    @Html.TextBox("criteria", "Search", new
        {
            @class = "searchbox",
            onfocus = "if (this.value==this.defaultValue) {this.value = ''}",
            onblur = "if (this.value=='') {this.value = this.defaultValue}"
        })
    <a class="btn btnStyleC btn-search quickSearch" href="javascript:searchSumbitOnClick();">Search</a> @*<a class="btn btnStyleC btn-search" href="javascript:searchSumbitOnClick();">Search</a>*@ } </div>
```

Comment: What have you done so far? Can you make your question more specific?

Comment: Hi Roman,

The code works as is but only when I enter one word (one value). 
I want to be able to search multiple values at the same time.

Comment: Can I enter multiple values in a single search box? 
I want to enter multiple product codes in a single search box and then the engine will return all the matching products.

Thank you for your time,
Bobby